# wxGrid Problem in wxWidgets 2.9.1

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

Hi All I have a code built in wxWidgets 2.6.3 I have complied that code in wxWidgets 2.9.1
But it has given error in using wxGrid Is wxGrid become obselete or whats the problem?

Comment: Why minus votes? Please comments, so that I can improve my questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short Answer: No. wxGrid is still there, with minor changes.

Long Answer:

2.6.3 was released in March, 2006, while 2.9.1 just came out back in July, 2010. That's over four years worth of changes. Many things have changed.

That aside, 2.9.1 is not intended to be compatible with 2.6.x, and in fact, as noted on the website as you download, 2.9.1 is a development release of wxWidgets, and is intended to be API/ABI incompatible (not just with the older stable 2.6 branch, but also with the current stable 2.8 branch).

Please see the docs/changes.txt file included with 2.9.1 for a detailed list of everything that has been changed since 2.6.3. There are way too many to name here.